# Combine compilation-mode and ansi-term-mode in Emacs?

Tags: terminal, emacs, compile

In Emacs, I would like to be able to combine the features of ansi-term-mode and compilation-mode. I have a build system for compiling my source code which uses terminal commands for placing the cursor. This is as to have progress bars and stuff. So I can use ansi-term-mode for kicking of the build process, but I lose the error-recognition of compilation-mode. Can I combine both? Either putting the error-recognition and "jumping into file" feature of compilation-mode into ansi-term-mode, or the other way around giving compilation-mode ansi-term features.

And yes, I could force the build tool to output dumb information, but I actually like the compact, progress bar view.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer to my own problem: the `compilation-minor-mode` is what I am looking for. You can use customize to add it to the `term-mode-hook`:

```
 '(term-mode-hook (quote (compilation-minor-mode)))
```

Answer (score 0):

compilation-shell-minor-mode works better than compilation-minor-mode because the keys are compatible with the term mode. Example: RET sends a return instead of trying to go to the next error.

This can be added to your .emacs

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook 'compilation-shell-minor-mode)
```

Or to turn on in a single term mode buffer:

```
C-x M-X compilation-shell-minor-mode
```